# jquery close auto suggest list when click somewhere outside

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery and I have written this script for an auto suggest search box. Everything works fine, but the list keeps to remain open when the users clicks outside it, somewhere in page. I found 2 similar examples here of how to get rid of this, but It couldn't work for me. Any idea how to do it? This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#search_form_1').keyup(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();

    if(value != ''){
        $('#search_result').show();
        $.post('search_form.php', {value: value}, function(data){
            $('#search_result').html(data);
        }); 

    }else{
        $('#search_result').hide();
    }

});

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [blur function](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)  when triggers,when it loses `focus`.

```
$('#search_form_1').blur(function(){
    $('#search_result').hide();
});
```

Comment: Glad I could help you out:)

Answer (score 0):

how about the blur event?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#search_form_1').keyup(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();

    if(value != ''){
        $('#search_result').show();
        $.post('search_form.php', {value: value}, function(data){
            $('#search_result').html(data);
        }); 

    }else{
        $('#search_result').hide();
    }

})
.blur(function(){
     $('#search_result').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will hide the result when the 'blur' event is triggered, so when #search_form_1 loses focus, which will happen when a users clicks outside of the element.

```
$('#search_form_1').blur(function(){
    $('#search_result').hide();
});
```